# WMI Query - First and Fourth IP octet

Tags: windows, group-policy, wmi, query

Is anyone aware of any WMI queries that could be used within group policy which only lists all IP address, which end in .200 and

I have multiple sites, multiple networks, I only need to list the devices that end with .200 and start with 192.

for example 192.1.1.200, 192.168.122.200, I would like an WMI query that see's 192.%.%.200 (1st octet and 4th) only.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if you could test with something like `WMIC NICCONFIG GET IPADDRESS,MACADDRESS /FORMAT:CSV | FINDSTR /R ".[192]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[200]."` to get the expected results.  Let me know whether or not you find any use of that. I assume looking in DNS and sorting there isn't sufficient?

Comment: Are you asking about a WMI Filter that you could apply to a GPO, such that the settings in the GPO would only apply to machines that match the given criteria?

Comment: Hi Lmfao_A_Joke,

DNS isn't enough I'm afraid, I'll try your suggestion out soon.

@ Ryan Ries, yeah looking for a WMI filter to apply to a GPO.

Any ideas?

Comment: @AlexD Did you determine anything with this yet? Be sure when you type in my name to tag me that you include the "@" symbol followed by my username with NO SPACES. When it autopopulates, just click on it... This way I get the notification otherwise I will not get a notification and will have to remeber to check this post manually.